# How to Exclude Weekends and holidays using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

[image]I am trying to write code in PowerShell to exclude weekends and holidays, but I'm getting errors, can you please help me with that?

```
$a = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"
#Get-Date -format "dddd yyyy-MM-dd"

if($a.DayOfWeek -eq 'Tuesday')
{
    Write-Host "tuesday"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "false"
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve] (incl. full error stack)…

Comment: i was edited can u look once  and provide solution plz

Comment: can u please provide solution asap. its high priority for me

Comment: @MohammadHafiz You say you're "getting errors", but there's no error messages in your post. Please show us the full error messages if you want help debugging. Please remember that you are the only person who can see your screen :)

Comment: I have shared screenshot. my error is false but today also tuesday then it needs to display tuesday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It is recommended to use `Set-StrictMode` for your development scripts to identify code issues.](https://powershell-guru.com/powershell-best-practice-11-use-set-strictmode-in-your-dev-scripts)

From [`Get-Help Set-StrictMode -online`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Set-StrictMode):

> The `Set-StrictMode` cmdlet configures strict mode for the current
> scope and all child scopes, and turns it on and off. When strict mode
> is on, PowerShell generates a terminating error when the content of an
> expression, script, or script block violates basic best-practice
> coding rules.

You get an exhaustive answer to your question immediately using `Set-StrictMode`:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$a=Get-Date  -format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$a.DayOfWeek -eq 'Tuesday'
```

> ```
> The property 'DayOfWeek' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
> At line:3 char:1
> + $a.DayOfWeek -eq 'Tuesday'
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
> ```

Comment: i am asking about how to exclude weekends . if($a.DayOfWeek -eq 'Tuesday') but its not working. can u help me

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from thefact that you are converting the date from `Get-Date` into a **string** using `-Format "yyyy-MM-dd"`

```
$a = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$a.GetType()
```

shows that $a is now a string.
Strings do not have a `DayOfWeek` property as [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) objects do.

Simply remove the `-Format` part

```
$a = Get-Date

if($a.DayOfWeek -eq 'Tuesday') {
    Write-Host "Today is Tuesday"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Today is NOT Tuesday"
}
```

Comment: Hi,   after excluding holiday need to exclude one working day to update my file

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's useful to use dates as numbers:

```
$weekday = ( @(1..5).foreach( {$_ -eq [int](Get-Date).dayofweek} ) -contains $true )  
if ($weekday) {"Work"} else {"Not a weekday"}  
$weekend = ( @(6,0).foreach(  {$_ -eq [int](Get-Date).dayofweek} ) -contains $true )  
if ($weekend) {"Rest"} else {"Not the weekend"}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).